# Change required reputation to edit/close a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been thinking about this for a while, and I think it might be more useful to switch the required reputation to edit/close, making edit be at 3000, and close at 2000. Not sure if it's even possible, but I thought I'd at least ask what other's thoughts are on the topic.

Comment: FWIW, there's currently 16 users with >3k and 23 with >2k.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't mind considering it, but there's no actual argument to do so in your question. Can you add your reasoning why you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are some radical changes coming to editing, so you might want to table that part of it for the time being.

I think closing requires a lot of experience on the site, so 3k feels about right to me and I would be uncomfortable changing that without a *lot* of evidence in favor of the change.

If you think there needs to be more reputation in your site's economy, please Vote Early and Often and encourage others to as well!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Comment: Considering I almost always max out my votes per day, well...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the privileges are granted in just about the right order as they stand now. Someone with 2K reputation has probably demonstrated enough knowledge of the territory to be able to restate or clarify a question -- that may mean being able to pick out technical terms used regionally, or recognising terms that the asker has tried to use incorrectly -- in order to make it easier to answer and search. Closing a question, though, is more of a community conscience thing, and should require a bit of seniority. Sure, there are some things that are obviously and egregiously off-topic, and as in any other online community there are going to be people who are asking the same question that currently sits at number five on the hot list, but there are a lot more instances where it's a bit of a judgment call. I'd hate to see this become a place where subtlety is not allowed at all -- there are things that are similar, but not similar enough to be shut down as asked and answered. We're involved in an artistic endeavor as much as a technical one, and there ought to be cooler heads tyling the door.